# Difference between docker-compose restart <service> and docker restart <service>?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I think I have an understanding of this but just would like some clarification.

I have a docker-compose file with all my services in it.  Did a docker-compose up and everything is fine.  One of my services is a worker that needs to be restarted whenever my files change.  For now I do a bind-mount from my host to the container.  When I make some changes on my local system and then restart the worker container and it should pick up the changes.

If I do docker-compose restart , then it works and my changes are picked up.

If I do docker restart , then it seems to just cache the old environment, the files my worker runs are the "old" ones even though I can see the file changed when I ssh into the container.

I'm guessing it has something to do with docker-compose reloading configs or something?  For now I'm just going continue to use docker-compose restart but I'd like a better understanding of what's going on.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: docker run/start/restart is just running a container for you. docker compose is doing a lot more - creating a network and running there all the services you have specified in your file.

Comment: Coud you provide a minimal, reproducible example where this occurrs? To this point, my test setups react the same way to `docker restart` and `docker-compose restart`.

Comment: If you use docker-compose to start your service then you should use the same to manage them. Almost all commands of docker are implemented in docker-compose as well (run, exec, log, ps, etc.) and they work at service level instead of at container level. Keep in mind that docker-compose also automatically picks up .env files and override files that you might miss if you use docker commands.

Comment: @bellackn For instance, if my config is just launching a standard web server then docker restart service and docker-compose restart service behave the same.

I have a service that starts up a php script that listens for jobs on a beanstalk queue.  If I update any of my app files I need to restart the container so that the script can pick up my updated files.  It seems to ignore any changes to the files I made, even if on the container I can view the file and it's changed.  Have to docker-compose down and back up to get the changes to stick, or docker-compose restart service.

Comment: I see. Well, I don't have any experience with PHP, so I can't really try something myself here without a code example. What you could try is monitoring the logs of the container and observe whether it reacts differently (another exit signal maybe?) on `docker restart` and `docker-compose restart`. Also, you could try the same when restarting just the process in the container with `docker exec -it [container] [cmd_to_restart_php]` vs. `docker-compose exec [...]`.